# Artists and music - Need Help Deciding on a CMS

Tags: wordpress, cms, drupal, music

A friend has asked me to build a site with the following options:

- staff members must be able to add new music and artists to the page
- a gallery must be provided - it is also good if each artist has the ability to have his/her own smaller gallery
- users must be able to vote for artists
- users must be able to alter in discussions (forums or comments sections)
- staff members must be able to blog
- staff members must be able to write articles

I did a small project where i actually implemented all of these features, but I want to  use an existing content management system for all of these features so that future developers can, hopefully, more easy extend the website. And also, so that I don't have to provide too much documentation.

I have never developed a website using an external CMS like Drupal or Wordpress and after seeing hours of tutorial videos of both systems, I still can't make up my mind on whether i should :

a) use Drupal 7
b) use Wordpress 3
c) create my own cms

I can imagine that staff members would also want to create content using iPhone or android based mobile devices, but this is not a required feature.

Can someone, with experience, please tell me about their experiences with larger projects like this?

The site will have approximately 400 000 - 500 000 visitors (not daily visitors, based on numbers from last year in a period of 4 months)

Answer (score 1):

This could certainly be accomplished using WordPress. It would take some custom development, but some of your requirements could be met using plugins, which would reduce development time significantly. You might want to ask for more detail  on how your different requirements could be met at the [WordPress Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[SquareSpace](http://squarespace.com) should do most of this out-of-the-box, except maybe for the voting. You can customize who has access to what pretty easily via user accounts and audiences. Their modules include forums, galleries, blogs, and many other things. The voting might be something you can custom add onto it if you need to.

You can create a free account in a few minutes, and play around with it. You'll have two weeks to do what you want with it without paying a dime, and unless you actually officially sign up for the paid version, you won't give them your credit card, so you won't be charged anything.